# Multipage registration form with Ctools

Tags: forms, users, chaos-tool-suite

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on multipage user registrations at http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools, but I'm doing something wrong. As it's written, if I put `function hook_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &form_state) {`, it throws me a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE` error; however, if I change the `&form_state` to `&$form_state`, it doesn't complain.

HOWEVER

It seems as if this form isn't replacing the existing form. There's a button added to the registration form *Create new account* (the standard Drupal *continue* button is still there). The rest of the standard Drupal form is still the same (just username and password fields).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which is your PHP version ?

Comment: PHP 5.3.13 on WAMP

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function grasmash_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'] = array(
    'user_register_submit',
    'ctools_wizard_submit',
  );
}
```

Comment: nope - didn't work - thanks, though

Comment: sorry I dont have enough information to understand where the problem is all I can tell you is you cant call a function using "hook" you have to replace it with the module name and I think the problem is there if its not I need to ask you if you followed the tutorial step by step as it is so I can try it and see if I get the same error

Comment: Maybe this will help - my module file is at http://pastebin.com/ZAuqqrQb, and my inc file is at http://pastebin.com/rt2B2vkz. The info file is at http://pastebin.com/JdZ1hf34

Answer (score 0):

from your question, it is obvious you had a typo in the function header. 
Php variable name must start with $ but you typed & f o r m _ s t a t e instead of & $f o r m _ s t a t e

The & only instruct that the $f o r m _ s t a t e be passed by reference.